# Bazel nested C/C++ packages, what is the recommended BUILD structure?

Tags: c++, c, bazel

Let's say I'm considering a directory structure that looks something like the following for a `C` project using the `bazel` build system.

```
/util
  util.c
  util.h
  /error
    error.c
    error.h
  /math
    math.c
    math.h
    /linalg
      matrix.c
      matrix.h
```

And, the following additional requirements:

1. Each directory should be built as a `cc_library` that contains or relinks its child `cc_libraries`.
2. `cc_libraries` (or their children) will depend on sibling `cc_libraries`. For example, `matrix.c` may `#include error.h`.

Are there ways to preserve this structure when using `bazel` that don't result in difficult to maintain `BUILD` files? Are nested packages usable?

```
/util
  BUILD
  util.c
  util.h
  /error
    BUILD
    error.c
    error.h
  /math
    BUILD
    math.c
    math.h
    /linalg
      BUILD
      matrix.c
      matrix.h
```

Or, should the folder structure simply take a shallower form?

```
/util
  BUILD
  util.h
  util.c
/error
  BUILD
  error.c
  error.h
/math
  BUILD
  math.c
  math.h
/linalg
   BUILD
   matrix.c
   matrix.h
```

Comment: For reference, Bazel packages don't really have a nesting structure. The names form a folder hierarchy, but AFAIK the only part of Bazel that treats them as such is the `__subpackages__` visibility syntax. Everything else treats them as a flat list, and it's very common for their folders to be nested like your first structure.

Comment: Should I change the title, or just leave it so someone else who has the same mental model finds this?

Comment: Seems fine to me. I think it's a reasonable question, and Chris gave a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think either approach could work, but I prefer the first.
There's no rule dictating what can (or cannot) depend on what, as long as it's visible to the rule and no cycles are formed.  A heuristic like "deps only go sideways or down" doesn't prevent, but can help in avoiding cycles.

Nothing looks particularly difficult to maintain from this example, just specify your deps as needed:

```
cc_library(
    name = "linalg",
    hdrs = [ "matrix.h" ],
    srcs = [ "matrix.c" ],
    visibility = [ "//visibility:public" ],
    deps = [ "//util/error" ],
)
```

Etc.

Comment: I think your reference to "sibling packages that depend on each other" is referring to circular dependencies, but I think it's unclear to somebody not aware of that problem. Could you clarify that it's only a problem if they both depend on each other, and one depending on another is fine?

Comment: reworded for clarity.